# settinging latitude,longitude of gps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps

I want to test some features.
how can i set hard coded my latitude,longitude of iPhone gps?
I know how to get it...

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
 {
 lat =  newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
 lon = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;


 }
```

but didnt found a way setting it

Comment: If you are in simulator, then take a look at Debug->Location menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your **Simulator**, in the top bar go to **Debug=>Location=>Custom Location** enter your custom latitude and longitude coordinates.

Comment: thanks, it helped for testing, but how can i change it in the code **programmatically**?

Comment: welcome. What do you mean change in the code? that is meant to use as a virtual current location. you can set it only manually

Comment: to set it with diffrent values , something like this maybe `coordinate.latitude = 32.6665;`

Comment: if you want to set that coordinate to your current location u have to do it manually from the above link.

Comment: I explain again, i'm working on a map that uses my lat,lon for displaying it on the map.To show some features i need to set my lat,lon to another place and start some methods, through the simulator its fine but i need it to be dynamically in the code so i can set it to different values

Comment: do you mean you want to change your current location from time to time  while your apps is running?

Comment: yeah, well not changing it all the time but to change it once, yes.

Comment: that is not possible on simulator... you have to test it on the real device. the current location remains same until you manually change it

Comment: yeah for testing on real device i need some how to change it..you saying it's impossible changing on device?

Comment: no its impossible changing on simulator... its only possible on real device

Comment: I want to change it on real device...how can i do it?

Comment: you have to move around with your device to change your current location